# jquery uniform select and deselect all checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with select all / deselect checkbox

**Code Here**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" onclick="checkedAll();" name="checkall" id="checkall"/>

  function checkedAll() {
      $('.all span').click(function () {
       if(document.getElementById("checkall").checked == true)
       {
         $('#uniform-undefined span').addClass('checked');      
       }
       else
       {
         $('#uniform-undefined span').removeClass('checked');
       }
     });
     $.uniform.update();
   }
```

When I select checkbox(for all check box true) jQuery add span tag with `class="checked"`

```
     spanTag.addClass(options.checkedClass);
```

And no one check box are active.

```
<li><label><div id="uniform-undefined" class="checker">">
   <span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" value="F2" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
   </div><b>1 </b>
 </label></li>

<li><label><div id="uniform-undefined" class="checker">
   <span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" value="F2" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
   </div><b>2 </b>
</label></li>

<li><label><div id="uniform-undefined" class="checker">
    <span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" value="F3" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
    </div><b>3 </b>
</label></li>
```

Comment: are you trying to select all with one click

Comment: what are you trying to do in the code ?

Comment: Can you ensure the code you show is correct and has no copy-paste errors. you seem to have an additional `">` in the beginning and you `style=opacity: 0;"` in the last set is missing a `"`. Just want to make sure the issue is not due to odd HTML.

Comment: If you simply want to check all checkboxes, do something like: `$('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', true)`;

Comment: A JSfiddle will be much appreciated...

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aiming for something like this ?

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#all').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.group').attr("checked",true);
        }
        else{
            $('.group').attr("checked",false);
        }
    })
});
```

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/uSX6p/)

Comment: You should be using the property "checked", not the attribute "checked". $('.group').prop("checked");

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
  $('#all').on('click', function(){
        $(':checkbox').attr("checked",$(this).is(':checked'));
  });
```

OR for the las version.

```
  $('#all').on('click', function(){
        $(':checkbox').prop("checked",$(this).is(':checked'));
  });
```

See this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfzdh/)...

Comment: i saw what you did there :) , pretty neat

Comment: This works well but no with latest jQuery versions as they have removed `attr` and added `prop` instead. SO just update the code and ad `prop` instead `attr` and it will work good :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#all').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('.group').attr("checked",true);
        }
        else{
            $('.group').attr("checked",false);
        }
    })
});
```

this is code is correctly working for the first time only. For the second time if i click the check all check box it is not working. It only got checked.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution call uniform.update:

```
        $(".all span").each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", document.getElementById("checkall").checked );
        });
        $.uniform.update();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#selectAll').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#uniform-undefined span').attr("class","checked");
        }
        else{
            $('#uniform-undefined span').attr("class","");
        }
    })
});
</script>
```